# Is there "toffset" option for \setupbackgrounds in context

Tags: context

I'm trying to learn `context`, and I'm satisfied with their capacities.

I read in [contextgarden](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/setupbackgrounds) that options of `\setupbackgrounds` inherit from `\setupframed`, but if I setup `toffset=5mm` for  `\setupbackgrounds[text][text][frame=on,toffset=5mm]` I have no effect?

With `frameoffset` you can modify the four directions but how about a single direction?

**Code**

```
\setuppapersize[A4]
\setuppagenumbering[state=none]

\setupbackgrounds[text][text][frame=on,toffset=5mm]

\starttext

\input knuth


\stoptext
```

Comment: https://www.mail-archive.com/ntg-context@ntg.nl/msg80961.html

Comment: @DG' Do you want to turn this into an answer?

Comment: @TeXnician shouldn't Wolfgang?

Comment: @DG' Well you have found the answer on the mailing list, so why not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Wolfgang Schuster](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/33961/wolfgang-schuster) gave an answer on the [ConTeXt mailing list](https://www.mail-archive.com/ntg-context@ntg.nl/msg80961.html):

> The background mechanism for the text areas supports only a fraction of the normal framed options but you can do a lot when you use Metapost to draw the background.

```
\startuniqueMPgraphic{TextBackground}
    path p ; p := unitsquare xscaled OverlayWidth yscaled OverlayHeight ;
    draw p topenlarged 5mm ;
    setbounds currentpicture to OverlayBox ;
\stopuniqueMPgraphic

\defineoverlay[TextBackground][\uniqueMPgraphic{TextBackground}]

\setuppapersize[A4]
\setuppagenumbering[state=none]

\setupbackgrounds[text][text][background=TextBackground]

\starttext

\input knuth

\stoptext
```